# getting started automating virtualization with powershell on windows

Tags: virtualization, automation, datacenter

What are some good books or resources for learning automate virtual PCs on Windows DataCenter?  I want to be able to build VPCs with both automated installs and from images, preferably via powershell.  I would like to be able to setup an IIS environment for automated testing, and configure end user installs of different versions of Windows.  I am not interested in corpnet type scenarios (active directory, domains, etc) so much for now.

I'm comfortable with powershell and programming in general.  I haven't yet installed Windows DataCenter, maybe once I install it will be clear enough.  But looking for resources on how to managed virtual PCs programmatically I haven't found anything.

Comment: Using Hyper-V or vSphere as the VM host platform?

Comment: I only have Hyper-V available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Virtual PC Guy's Blog" is a good start, he has covered scripting Hyper-V from PowerShell on multiple occasions: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/

Answer (score 0):

Powershell.org has a great community and a ton of resources (including ebooks). Start looking around on there for DSC specifically. Additionally, powershellmagazine.com has some great articles on the subject.